# How to write route for the scenario below

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a JSON route path that looks like this:

```
 /jobs/{jobid}/employees/{employeeid}/departments/cubes/{cubeid}/register
```

The following route works fine when there was no cube and cubed:

```
resources :departments, only: [] do
  get 'register', on: :collection
end
```

I tried doing this:

```
namespace :departments do
  resources :cubes, only: [] do
    get 'register', on: :collection
  end
end
```

What change do I need to do in the above code so it will work with the route path?

Comment: i don't see a department id in your path. is 'cubes' supposed to be a specific department?

Comment: I dont have departmentID. cubes are part of department. like employee cube in departments and each employeecube has id

Comment: if this is just a single route why not just define it rather than nesting it? e.g. `get /jobs/:job_id/employees/:employee_id/departments/cubes/:cube_id/register, to: ..., as: :register_employee_job_cube`

Comment: /departments/cubes, two consecutive path components being hard-coded, doesn't really make sense. You may as well get rid of /departments. Also, the path looks back-to-front,I'd expect it to be more like /cubes/{cubeId}/employees/{employeeId}/jobs/{jobId} if I understand what these terms mean.

Answer (score 0):

When I add:

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :employees do
    namespace :departments do
      get 'cubes/:cube_id/register',
        to: 'cubes#register'
    end
  end
end
```

to my `routes.rb` and then run `rake routes`, I get this line in my output:

```
GET /jobs/:job_id/employees/:employee_id/departments/cubes/:cube_id/register(.:format) departments/cubes#register
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to nest resources more than 1 level

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

> Rule of thumb: resources should never be nested more than 1 level
>   deep. A collection may need to be scoped by its parent, but a specific
>   member can always be accessed directly by an id, and shouldn’t need
>   scoping (unless the id is not unique, for some reason).